# How to map a function on the elements of a nested list

Tags: haskell

This is a trival question.

But what is the standard way to map a function (`+1` in this example) on nested list?

```
map (\x -> map (+1) x) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I use the above way in my code, but what is a good way to do that? Is there something like a `mapNested (+1) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` or similar? I used google and hoogle but got too much generic results.

Comment: If you want to, you can define `mapNested f xs = map (\x -> map f x) xs`. But the way you are doing it is the canonical way, if we exclude some typographical conventions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a few ways but the most obvious is:

```
Prelude> map (map (+1)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

This would be the textbook answer.

Maybe you like to do the outer part with a list comprehension?

```
Prelude> [ map (+1) xs | xs <- [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ]
[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

Or even the whole thing?

```
Prelude> [ [ x + 1 | x <- xs ] | xs <- [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ]
[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

Answer (score 17):

I don't think it defined anywhere in the standard library, but you can define it as such:

```
mapNested :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
mapNested = map . map
```

Or to make it more generic (ie. work on other functors than lists):

```
fmapNested :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmapNested = fmap . fmap
```

Example use:

```
fmapNested (+1) [Some 1, None, Some 3] -- == [Some 2, None, Some 4]
```

Comment: Is that really "as generic as possible"?  I mean... `incEverything  = everywhere (mkT ((+1) :: Int -> Int))`  and then `incEverything [ [Just 3, Just 54, Nothing] :: [Maybe Int] ] ~~> [[Just 4,Just 55,Nothing]]`

Comment: While it's equivalent to `fmap . fmap`, you could instead write `fmap fmap fmap` for this operation.  It's equivalent because the first `fmap` is being applied to the `(->) r` functor, which just becomes composition.  It is a rather fun abstraction, though, and it lets you map this nested computation 2 layers deep into any two functors.  It's also equivalently the `(.:) = (.) . (.)` operator but more generalized.

Comment: Lesson learned: never say "as generic as possible" in Haskell, or someone *will* give you an even more generic example :)

Comment: I saw `map . map` and it was a little counterintuitive to me so here's a...derivation

https://gist.github.com/skatenerd/767e2042f388bde63779

Comment: This is also defined in Stephen Diehl's Prelude alternative called protolude under the name `<<$>>`.

Answer (score 5):

You need composition of maps: `(map . map) (+1) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`